# ASP.Net MVC - can't change bootstrap version

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Asp.Net MVC, trying to create my first website.
I was using bootstrap v4.1.1 in my project until I noticed that a library I wanted to use doesn't support it.
So I uninstalled the package (in Package Manager Console) - and installed the new targeted version v3.3.0.

Made sure that my "\scripts\bootstrap.js" is v3.3.0.

Ran the application, view source, and... surprisingly it was still using v4.1.1!

Double checked the physical files in my solution folder and there is no other "bootstrap.js" flying around!

I then renamed the file to "bootstrap3.js" (and updated the "BundleConfig.cs" accordingly), and it worked!
But as soon as I revert the file name to the original "bootstrap.js", my website starts using v4.1.1 and I have no idea where the system is getting this file from!!!

This is too weird... Hoping someone here has an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: You got me embarrassed now. I struggled with this problem for hours, tried everything but haven't cleared the browser cache... and doing that fixes the problem. Thank you so much! If you want to create an answer I'll mark it. Thanks